# GWT TextBox Regex

Tags: regex, gwt

I am using GWT textBox and i want it to allow only alpha numeric characters.Is there any example somewhere where i can use the RegExp which is provided in GWT 2.1?

I would like to apply a regex for example `^[a-zA-Z0-9_]*$` .Please provide example code for making this working.Also i cannot use a third party library like the GWT-VL or something like that.

I am using GWT 2.1.

Thanks

Comment: Would you like to only allow user's input to be accepted into the textbox if it will match the regex, or would you like to message to the user that their input doesn't match?

Comment: i would like to allow user's input to be accepted into the textbox if the regex matches and also indicate the user with a message saying that the input doesn't match

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use the `matches` method of the class `String`.

Here an example of an email validation:

```
if(!email.matches("^([a-zA-Z0-9_.\\-+])+@(([a-zA-Z0-9\\-])+\\.)+[a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4}$")) {
    setErrorText("wrong mail");
}
```

Note that `email` is a `String` object.

Answer (score 0):

HI you can use GWT-Validator framnework to do this [GWT-Validator](http://techblog.maydu.eu/?p=7)

Or you can use javascript method through JSNI and the method is mentioned below.

```
function validate(var string){
  var alphanum=/^[0-9a-bA-B]+$/; //This contains A to Z , 0 to 9 and A to B
    if(string.match(alphanum)){
       return true;
    }else{
       alert(Put a Valid Userid Name);
       return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answer.I mentioned in the question that i cannot use the GWT-VL framework or for that matter any 3rd party frameworks

Comment: I have also mentioned code snipet of Javascript method that can be used using JSNI in GWT.